# UITableViewCell customization with lots of text inside

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm doing a custom UITableViewCell within which I should enter three text fields, now the problem lies in the fact that the field called ***Descirizione*** is really very wide and I should find a way to show all three fields ! this also gives me a problem in showing the field ***Prezzo*** that is moved when the field ***Descrizione*** is very large.

Image of Display Text is below

[image]

**CustomTableViewCellArticolo.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class CustomTableViewCellArticolo: UITableViewCell {

    let labCodArt = UILabel()
    let labDescrizione = UILabel()
    let labPrezzo = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        labCodArt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labDescrizione.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labPrezzo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(labCodArt)
        contentView.addSubview(labDescrizione)
        contentView.addSubview(labPrezzo)

        let viewsDict = [
            "CodArt": labCodArt,
            "Descrizione": labDescrizione,
            "Prezzo": labPrezzo,
        ] as [String: Any]

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[Prezzo]-15-[Descrizione]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[CodArt]-5-[Descrizione]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[CodArt]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[Descrizione]-[Prezzo]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**UIViewController.swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    TableViewArticoli.beginUpdates()
    let cell = TableViewArticoli.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCellArticolo
    cell.labCodArt.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].CodArt
    cell.labDescrizione.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].Descrizione
    cell.labPrezzo.text = " € \(filteredData[indexPath.row].Prezzo!)"
    TableViewArticoli.endUpdates()
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after this line :

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[Descrizione]-[Prezzo]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

Add this line:

```
labPrezzo.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.required, for: .horizontal)
labDescrizione.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: With your solution the Descrizione label is correctly seen the Prezzo label is no longer visible!

Comment: I'm updated the answer, did you checked that and used the new one?

Comment: Now the Prezzo is visible but the Descrizione is of variable size so in some cases the Prezzo is seen moved, is it possible to keep the Prezzo fixed on the right? (What happens is seen in the second line of the image above)

Comment: Replace this line `contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[Descrizione]-[Prezzo]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))` with these two lines and check what happens:
`contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[Descrizione]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))`
`contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[Prezzo]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))`